# Installing ubuntu 19.10 with boot mode set to UEFI with legacy OPROM

Tags: uefi

I have installed Ubuntu 19.10 on a Dell AIO.
Boot mode is set to UEFI LEGACY OPROM; secure boot off.

Do I need an EFI partition, or can I get rid of it?

Thank you to anyone who can advise.

Comment: I'd leave it be, especially if it was created by the installer automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, booting in UEFI mode needs an EFI system partition. There may be some variations of the properties of that partition, but if you remove it you would have to create a new one (or boot from another drive, where there is an EFI system partition) in order to boot in UEFI mode.

Necessary and possible partition tables and partitions are described in the following link,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace)

---

I am not quite sure what you mean by

> Boot mode is set to UEFI LEGACY OPROM

You can check if you are booting in UEFI mode or BIOS mode (alias CSM alias legacy mode) with the following command line

```
test -d /sys/firmware/efi && echo efi || echo bios
```